# Add ContextMenu under ComboBox in c#, when user click of left mouse press on combobox, it shows context menu

Tags: c#, combobox, contextmenu

Here is the code in Xaml and it works, add context menu under combobox

```
private void cboSingleSite_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
    {
        ComboBox image = sender as ComboBox;
        ContextMenu contextMenu = image.ContextMenu;
        contextMenu.PlacementTarget = image;
        contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }
 }
```

Here is the code in C# but not works help me.

```
private void cboSingleSite_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        ComboBox combo = sender as ComboBox;
        ContextMenu contextMenu = combo.ContextMenu;
        //ContextMenu cm = (ContextMenu)ContextMenu.ItemsControlFromItemContainer((MenuItem)e.OriginalSource);
        //combo.DisplayMember = "Text";
        combo.Items.Add(contextMenu);
    }
}
```

I am trying but can't make this work.

Comment: I used visual studio 2012. in windows, c# .net Framework  4.5.